# Flutter callback function with StreamBuilder()

Tags: flutter

First, sorry for bad English level.

I'm working on getting size of `Column` widget that has dynamic widgets and has `StreamBuilder` for its parent widget. I used `GlobalKey` to get the size of the `Column`. To get the size of the widget, the build process must be done, so the widget has actual size. I used `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` function to get the size of `Column`.

But here is the problem. I expect the callback function to be called after the `StreamBuilder` returns its child, but the callback function is called before the `StreamBuilder`, so callback function returns error message that `GlobalKey` has null value. I think `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` function is called after the build part is done. Is it wrong?

Comment: Hey, you are correct `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback function is called after the widget is done building`                    have you tried       `SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  print("SchedulerBinding");
});`